# Web scraper for Outlook Web App 2010?

Tags: outlook-web-access, screen-scraping

I've been using [weboutlook](http://code.google.com/p/weboutlook/) for years with great success, but recently we switched from the 2007 to the 2010 version of Outlook Web App (OWA).  Does anyone know of a scraper that works with the newer version?

Comment: Have you chegcked to see if the EWS or webdav APIs are allowwed on your Exchange server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Zoredache's helpful comment above, I've found an alternative.  [DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/) can experimentally act as an [EWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) client, and then re-serve email via POP or IMAP (using SSL, optionally).

Here's what I ended up doing, start to finish:

1. Find your Exchange server's EWS endpoint.  This may be as simple as **https://*your.server.com*/EWS/Services.wsdl**, but for me it was on a different domain.  I referred to the Macintosh documentation that my provider offers, because I guess both Mail and Entourage use EWS to communicate with Exchange.  When you find the right endpoint, you should have a standard HTTP authorization prompt and, after you authenticate, a SOAP WSDL.
2. Install Java on my server.
3. Follow the DavMail wiki's instructions on manually setting up [DavMail as a server](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/serversetup.html).  This was helpful for me because my server doesn't run X and the DavMail .deb comes with some GUI components.
4. Close the ports you don't need by removing the port values in the properties file.
5. Follow the DavMail wiki's instructions on [using SSL with DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/sslsetup.html).

Voilà!  Thanks again, Zoredache!